# Knockout : context changed before the instruction in observable.subscribe

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, knockout.js, observer-pattern

I'm trying to separate my Model from my ViewModel since I need the Model in two different ViewModel. So i've tried to this :

```
var ConversationManager = {
    conversations: ko.observableArray([
        {id: 3, receiver:'Toto'}
    ])
};

function ConversationDialogViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    ConversationManager.conversations.subscribe(function(context){
        console.log('Before :', context); // context.test == true ???

        for(var i = 0; i < context.length; i++){
            if(context[i].id % 2 == 0 && !context[i].test){
                console.log('Insertion Called');
                context[i].test = true;
            }
        }
        console.log('After :', context);
    });

    ConversationManager.conversations.push({id: 4, receiver:'Jean'});
    ConversationManager.conversations.push({id: 5, receiver:'Paul'});
    ConversationManager.conversations.push({id: 6, receiver:'Bleu'});
}
```

Somehow, in the first console.log, when i push "Jean", in the browser, the variable "test" exists and is correctly set to true even before i actually tell JS to do it. How is that possible ? 
And, am I correctly separating my concerns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the console references an object (where you can click an arrow to open it and look at its contents), it is still a reference, not a snapshot in time. As you modify `context`, it doesn't matter which reference to it in the debugger you look at, they will all be the same. You need to convert it to something that is static (or put in a breakpoint) if you want to see it at a moment in time.

```js
var ConversationManager = {
    conversations: ko.observableArray([
        {id: 3, receiver:'Toto'}
    ])
};

function ConversationDialogViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    ConversationManager.conversations.subscribe(function(context){
        console.log('Before :', JSON.stringify(context)); // context.test == true ???

        for(var i = 0; i < context.length; i++){
            if(context[i].id % 2 == 0 && !context[i].test){
                console.log('Insertion Called');
                context[i].test = true;
            }
        }
        console.log('After :', JSON.stringify(context));
    });

    ConversationManager.conversations.push({id: 4, receiver:'Jean'});
    ConversationManager.conversations.push({id: 5, receiver:'Paul'});
    ConversationManager.conversations.push({id: 6, receiver:'Bleu'});
}

new ConversationDialogViewModel();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> If you want to be notified of the value of an observable **before** it is about to be changed, you can subscribe to the `beforeChange` event.

You could try it this way:

```
ConversationManager.conversations.subscribe(function(context){
    // ...
}, null, "beforeChange");
```